# Maze algorithm: which line of code specifies that when a ball hits a dead end, it will backtrack?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am learning how to create a maze using Javascript. I went through the following code. Basically the logic is to randomly pick a square (I hard coded the value so I can better understand the pattern) and check if its neighbors have been visited or not. If so, just skip that neighbor and randomly choose an unvisited one and repeat the process by checking its neighbors again...I know that when the target hits a dead end, it will backtrack. But I didn't find any code that make the ball backtrack. Please see the image link here:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD7ME.png) [(3, 3) is a dead end. The for of loop checked that the left and the top were visited and the right and the bottom were out of bounds. My problem is that for(neighbor of neighbors){...} already looped through all four neighbors and the last iteration (in this case, checking the left square) was skipped because it was visited. But after the iteration, i immediately console log on the first line of the for of loop and surprisingly, the neighbors have changed from [[4, 3, "down"], [2, 3, "up"], [3, 4, "right"], [3, 2, "left"]] to [[3, 3, "down"],[1, 3, "up"],[2, 4, "right"],[2, 2, "left"]]. But wasn't the last iteration skipped with the continue key word and the iteration was supposed to end? Why I still got another four neighbors to loop through? Is this where the ball backtracks?

Thank you very much for your time! Much appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
    const width = innerWidth;
    const height = innerHeight;
    const cellsHorizontal = 4; // columns
    const cellsVertical = 4; // rows
    const unitLengthX = width / cellsHorizontal;
    const unitLengthY = height / cellsVertical;

    const stepThroughCell = (row, column) => {
  // If I have visited the cell at [row, column], then return
    if (grid[row][column]) {
    return;
   }

  // Mark this cell as being visited 
  grid[row][column] = true;

  // Specify neighbors
  const neighbors = [
    [row + 1, column, "down"], 
    [row - 1, column, "up"], 
    [row, column + 1, "right"], 
    [row, column - 1, "left"],
  ];

  // For each neighbor...
  for (neighbor of neighbors) {

    console.log(neighbors, row, column); // why we got another four neighbors after the last iteration was skipped? 
    
    const [nextRow, nextColumn, direction] = neighbor;

    // see if that neighbor goes to a cell that doesn't exist
    if (
      nextRow < 0 ||
      nextRow >= cellsVertical ||
      nextColumn < 0 ||
      nextColumn >= cellsHorizontal
    ) {
      continue;   
    }

    // If we have visited that neighbor, continue to next neighbor
    if (grid[nextRow][nextColumn]) {
      continue;

// the last iteration was skipped when the target hits a dead end, so the iteration was supposed to end? But the first line in the for of loop shows that there are another four neighbors, why?
    }

    // Remove a wall from either horizontals or verticals
    if (direction === "left") {
      verticals[row][column - 1] = true;
    } else if (direction === "right") {
      verticals[row][column] = true;
    } else if (direction === "up") {
      horizontals[row - 1][column] = true;
    } else if (direction === "down") {
      horizontals[row][column] = true;
    }
    
    // Visited that next cell
    stepThroughCell(nextRow, nextColumn);
  }
};

stepThroughCell(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive algorithm, actually you calling "stepThroughCell" inside if itself and continue/return on success/failure , so suppose you get dead end in some situation , the algorithm will continue from the last check point which "stepThroughCell" is called for another neighbor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My understanding is that the last iteration was skipped because there were no valid squares. So in this case, the browser skipped the iteration and went back to the beginning of the loop before the stepThroughCell function was called again. If the function was not called, how do we get new neighbors to check? 
I may not have a full understanding of how the loop works. Please let me know if my understanding is not correct. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: in this part of code `for (neighbor of neighbors)` you are iterating over all possible neighbors. so if algorithm fails anytime it will go back and tires with new node